# "Application not found" when opening folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems, windows-registry

I was experimenting with different file explorers and made one of them the default one (I believe it was One Commander). The software was since deleted so I cannot open the folder because there is no default file explorer. Is there a way I can change the default file explorer to be the windows 10 one through Regedit?

Here are some screenshots of the issue:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which file explorer was the one you uninstalled before the problem started?

Comment: Windows Explorer is always default, unless some other explorer was assigned to be default. What might you have done (abnormally) that there is no explorer default?

Comment: What do you see if you right-click a folder, in the Open With section? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Please edit your question to answer the questions.

Comment: @harrymc I don't have an "open with" menu in the context menu, also thank you for the help

Comment: @gantendo OneCommander

Comment: maybe install OneCommander again, then uninstall it.

Comment: @Gantendo I reinstalled it and found out there was an option to remove it as default, should have checked it. Ether way thanks a lot, how do I resolve this?

Comment: @ECOODER - Resolve what exactly? I seems your problem is entirely due to OneCommander.

Comment: Sorry - for a folder, the open options are normally at the top of the context menu. What do you see there, and what happens when you click them?